# Is it correct to say "work twice as hard than"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The full sentence is:
I worked at the very least twice as hard to close sales than back then [two months before].

If it's incorrect how do you say it then — "twice as hard as [at some specific time]"?

Comment: "As hard as" - "harder than". Technically you are working harder than but "as hard" requires "as".

Answer (score 3):

In British English: "I worked at the very least twice as hard to close sales as [I did] back then.

*Edited to remove surmise about US English. Doug Warren says it is the same as for UK.*

Comment: Speaking as an American, no I wouldn't.  I would use "as" as well.  I would only use "than" if it were phrased like "work two times harder than".

Answer (score 0):

I would rephrase: "Two months ago, I was working twice as hard as I do now to close sales."

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is an abridged version of " ... to close sales than (I did) back then." Editorially, I would accept it. An alternative construct is to say "... as I did back then". For a specific time you could also say "... as I did in July".

Comment: I don't see how adding "I did" makes "than" valid. On the other hand "as I did then" is fine but that is because, by using that phrase, you have repeated "as".